# How to disable a CMAKE option

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

On `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/JUCE`, there is:

```
option(JUCE_BUILD_EXTRAS "Add build targets for the Projucer and other tools" OFF)

if(JUCE_BUILD_EXTRAS)
    add_subdirectory(extras)
endif()
```

link: https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L57

So this is what I did:

```
set(JUCE_BUILD_EXTRAS OFF)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/JUCE)
```

However it still tries to build extras. I'm on Android Studio.

What should I do?

I also tried `set(JUCE_BUILD_EXTRAS OFF)`

The default value is OFF and even then it tried to build.

I always get these errors when trying to disable something on Android CMAKE but it always fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to guarantee that this will be overridden correctly from a parent `CMakeLists.txt` is to set it as a `CACHE` variable with a `FORCE`d value:

```
set(JUCE_BUILD_EXTRAS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/JUCE)
```

This will ensure that any state that may already exist from a previous configuration of the project that defines the `option` will be overridden and picked up first.

---

Technically, the documentation for [`option`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) states:

> ... If  is already set as a normal or cache variable, **then the command does nothing.**

However, this is only true if there have been no prior configurations -- so this only works if the variable was set *before the first configuration*

In practice I've found that the `FORCE`-approach is much more reliable.